# Php object loading pattern

Tags: php, mysql, oop

Sorry for this really bad title.

I have an object class, and an objectManager class used to get all the objects. (This is an example).

I can create an object with `new Object($id);`

If the id argument is present then the object make an sql query and fill itself with the data.

I want to make a table of all my objects, displaying their values.

Should i use the objectManager class to make a big SQL query that will return everything I need, or juste get a list of id and then load each object individually in a loop ?

I think that making only one query is better, but the code is really easier to read with the second solution.

What's your favorite method ?

Thanks

Comment: I know that this question may be too broad, but sometimes we just need to be pointed in the right direction.
Also, if you have a better title, feel free to change it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have one query only, and the Objects should then be hydrated with the relevant data without having to pass an ID. You could implement a Hydrate or exchangeArray method:

example:

```
public function exchangeArray(array $data){
$this->property1=$data['property1'];
$this->property2=$data['property2'];
$this->property3=$data['property3'];
return $this;
}
```

**EDIT**

You could also process this in your Object constructor:

```
public function __construct($argument){

    if(is_numeric($argument)){
    //treat as ID
    return $this->findById($argument);
    }elseif(is_array($argument)){
    //hydrate object without call to DB
    return $this->exchangeArray($argument);
    }
}
```

You may want to look at the Doctrine project which provides an off the shelf object relational mapper layer:

http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm.html

see also the Repository pattern:

http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html

Comment: You're welcome. I've also improved my answer, please see edit above. You can modify your object class to accept either a numeric ID or an array which would hydrate the object with the given array rather than the DB. Please accept answer if satisfied.